# Using DRF Serializers + Renderers to Make Requests to Other Servers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to use the Django Rest Framework `Serializers` and `Renderers` to make requests to other servers?

Let's say I have two servers both using DRF with the same `Models` and the same `Serializers` defined. I want to `POST` a model from one server and de-serialize it on the other side.

What is the best way to do this?

I came across the [MultiPartRenderer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers#multipartrenderer), but it labeled as "not suitable as a response renderer, but is instead used for creating test requests".

Answer (score 0):

While the MultiPartRenderer *may* work, you should use a more consistent renderer and parser, such as JSON.

In our server setup, when doing requests across servers we always use JSON (or XML, for legacy applications) as the renderer and parser allow for consistent responses that are always compatible.

You should look into other request libraries, such as [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/), that will allow you to make HTTP requests.

Comment: The reason that I am looking at `MultiPartRenderer` is that it supports sending files where I believe simple (without base64, etc) JSON does not. I am currently using `requests` but I do i have to manually create the data payload that I hand it. It would be great if there was a more consistent way of using the same Serializers that I have already defined to create the payload from the Model object.

Comment: It looks like it is possible: https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1990. My question is how would I go about using the renderer to initiate the request?